# Return the whole row of max value of multiple elements

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id_this_table   fk_tableX    fk_tableY    ts_started    ts_activated     ts_expired
      1             1            1        2019-03-20     2019-03-21      2019-03-22
      2             1            2        2019-03-23     2019-03-24      2019-03-25
      3             2            3        2019-03-23     2019-03-24      2019-03-26
```

I need to to get the most recent of every element by fk_tableX, for multiple elements. It's like a subscription, i need to get the most current one of every "client"

the results should look like this

```
  id_this_table   fk_tableX    fk_tableY  ts_started    ts_activated     ts_expired
      2             1            2        2019-03-23     2019-03-24      2019-03-25
      3             2            3        2019-03-23     2019-03-24      2019-03-26
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Why are there no rows with `fk_tableX` = 2?

Comment: there was, sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where t1.ts_expired=( select max(ts_expired) from table_name t2 where t1.fk_tableX=t2.fk_tableX)
```

or use row_number() if your dbms support

```
with cte as
(select t.*,row_number() over(partition by fk_tableX order by ts_expired desc) rn from table_name t
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: @ScottHunter according to description it seems to me that is typo because ts_expired is 25 and 26 which is not relevant with double one btw thanks for notifying